# Action Script 3 How to make an if statement that activates with array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement

If I made an if statement and I wanted it to do something when the target hits another movie clip(I already know how to do that) but only if its the right target, how would I do that?

```
function stopdrag(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(destination) || //right here is where the script would `check the name of the target// ){`
        scaryface.visible=true;
    }
}
```

how would I make sure it only works if the target is a specific value from an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom property of that target like ID (arr[0].ID = "abc") or something like that at the time of creating that array, and then you can check the ID.

And if the condition is that you are trying to match any of the value in array, then you can check with the index in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're asking. If you're trying to check whether the target is CONTAINED inside of an array you can use something like the following code:

```
function stopdrag(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(destination) && yourArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget) > 0){
         scaryface.visible=true;
    }
}
```

This will check whether the target collides with the destination and if so will check whether the target is contained inside of yourArray.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a switch/case or nested if statements... if you dont have an incredible amount of targets... for example:

```
if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(destination1){
doSomething();
}else if{
(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(destination2){
doSomethingElse();
}
```

Elsewise, something like Vipul's solution above is quite wise

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest and laziest way to do it without thinking about performance is

```
if(array.indexOf(e.currentTarget) >= 0){
    //do something
}
```